# How do I refresh parent component when I successfully make API call from child component, which is a modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have home page with a table having few entries. Above table I have button called add entry. When user clicks on add entry, it opens a modal, where user can add few details and submit it. The submit button makes API call to store the data in database. Once the API call is successful, the modal closes. Now , how do I refresh the parent component after modal closes so that the newly added data can be shown in table (which is loaded via API call). I'm using functional components. I'm looking for steps that I should follow, not full code (pseudo code will do ). I'm not using redux. i dont want to do winow.reload(). as it reloads the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

make an `async fetchData` function that will fetch you table data all you have passed that `fetchData` function to modal and on success call that fetch function

```
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false)
const [data,setData] = useState()

  const fetchPlans = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const getDataRes = await getData();
      // save that data in state that will reredener page
      setData(getDataRes.data);
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } finally {
    setLoading(false);
    }  
   };
</>
```

Comment: Will this work without useeffect hooks ?

Comment: nope the state is the trigger that will re-render your component

Comment: the state has to be passed in array as second argument in useEffect ? Thanks

Comment: define this function in parent just pass this function as a prop to the modal component when this event is triggered by modal it will set the state and thus your component will re-render, and you parent useEffect dependency list should'be empty we only want to run it on page render then after we trigger the event

Answer (score 0):

You can create a callback function in the parent component and pass it to children component as a property